# DFSR Replicate folder wizard targets incompatible error

Tags: dfs-r

I have the following setup:

- DFS namespace host: Windows 2008 R2 Standard server (Server1)
- Source folder: NetApp CIFS filer share advertising DFS capabilities mapped to the above DFS hosting server (NetAppCIFSFiler)
- Target replication folder: Windows 2012 R2 Enterprise local shared folder (Server2)

When trying to run the Replicate Folder Wizard on the DFS host (Server1), I get the following error:

> NetAppCIFSFiler: It is not possible to determine whether the server is
>   a cluster. Indicates two revision levels are incompatible.

Is it possible to use DFSR with my current setup and if so, apart from the obvious stated cause, how to address the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it seems that this isn't possible. Microsoft say the following:

While DFS-N service can leverage and include CIFS shares exposed also by third party vendors (NetApp in this case), DFS-Replication is a totally different service and it requires:

1. A Windows server Operating system where the DFS Replicaton Role has to be installed
2. a local disk, a DAS LUN or even a SAN/NAS/iSCSI LUN that has to be managed by the OS like a local disk  so:

   - Visibile as a disk under "Disk Management" console or via command "diskpart list disk"
   - Formatted with NTFS file system

Should Windows 2008 R2 Standard server (Server1) see the NetApp disk only as a CIFS share, this is not sufficient to include it in a DFS-R solution, because DFS-R service needs a local disk, NTFS file system and NTFS USN Journal log to detect changes and notify all replication partners, so this configuration is not supported.

Pretty clear answer and understandable so fair enough.